# OpenCV Filter2D iPhone with Kernel

Tags: ios, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to define a custom kernel for OpenCV on iOS.  I cannot seem to find a definitive method to do this.  The method that I have seen some other people use is this one, and I can't seem to get it to work exactly how I want it to.  I am using the cVVideoCamera delegate like this:

```
- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image;
{
// Do some OpenCV stuff with the image

  double m[] =    {1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                  2.0, 2.0, 2.0,
                  1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
  cv::Mat kernel = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32FC2, m);
  int ddepth = -1;

  cv::filter2D(image, image, ddepth, kernel);

}
```

This does not seem to work.  I think it might be because of the type in the cv:Mat constructor (CV_32FC2).  Does anyone know what this should be for an iPhone camera usually?  Or is there some other problem?

Comment: If I may, I can suggest an alternative to OpenCV for this: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage . The GPUImage3x3ConvolutionFilter lets you specify a kernel like this and the GPU acceleration it provides makes it far faster than OpenCV when handling video from the camera.

Comment: I actually have used GPUImage to do this already!  I am looking for a cross platform way to do it (Android and iOS), so I was looking into a way to reproduce it on iOS.  Let me know if you ever move GPUImage to Android though ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type CV_32FC2 does not refer to the type of the image you are passing in, it refers to the type in the kernel you are making.  Change the type of m to be float and change CV_32FC2 to CV_32f and it should work.  You also should give Brad Larson's framework a try like he suggests if performance is a problem.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work!  As I stated above, the only reason I'm not using GPUImage is because I am trying to re-use the code for Android.  Thanks though!